# Creating year-week column from string column for time series analysis python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to run a VAR (Vector Auto Regression) model on a data that I would aggregate to year-week format. My dates do not match with iso calendar of fiscal week (they are custom, used by the company)

I have the following format:

```
PROMO_WEEK
2018-PW-01
2018-PW-02
2018-PW-03
.
.
.
2019-PW-52
```

I would like to receive the following format **recognized as date**

```
PROMO_WEEK
2018-01
2018-02
2018-03
.
.
.
2019-52
```

I tried:

```
date_id_promo_week_id['PROMO_WEEK'] = pd.to_datetime(date_id_promo_week_id['PROMO_WEEK'], format = '%y-PW-%W')
```

But it gives error, and I cannot find a specific solution for that problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't have both. You can either have a `datetime64[ns]` column, which will not display in that format, but has full `datetime` functionality, or you can have your string format, which seems to only require you to `.str.replace('-PW', '')`

Comment: It can be confusing at first but the `format` parameter is so that you can parse non-conventional formats **into** the standardized `datetime64[ns]` format, not so that you can change the format of the `datetime64[ns]` column itself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot have both. It's either `datetime` in the correct format, or `string` as your expected output.

What's also going wrong is that `%W` expects a day value as well, so we artifically add it:

---

#### Option 1: as `datetime`:

```
df['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PROMO_WEEK'].str.replace('-PW', '')+'0', format='%Y-%W%w')

   PROMO_WEEK    new_col
0  2018-PW-01 2018-01-07
1  2018-PW-02 2018-01-14
2  2018-PW-03 2018-01-21
```

---

#### Option 2: as `string`, in expected format:

```
df['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['PROMO_WEEK'].str.replace('-PW', '')+'0', format='%Y-%W%w').dt.strftime('%Y-%W')


   PROMO_WEEK  new_col
0  2018-PW-01  2018-01
1  2018-PW-02  2018-02
2  2018-PW-03  2018-03
```